# Por que isso pode acontecer em um foreach?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, foreach, método

Eu construí duas classes simples:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Aluna {
   String nome;
   String idade;
   String cpf;

List<Aluna> listar(){
  ArrayList<Aluna> aluns = new ArrayList<>();
  Aluna aluna;
 
 aluna = new Aluna();
 aluna.cpf="839457476";
 aluna.idade="30";
 aluna.nome="Tereza ";
 aluns.add(aluna);
 
 aluna = new Aluna();
 aluna.cpf="89437298472";
 aluna.idade="17";
 aluna.nome="Aline";
 aluns.add(aluna);
 return aluns;
  }
}

 public class Start {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(Aluna al : new Aluna().listar()){
        System.out.println(al.cpf);
        System.out.println(al.idade);
        System.out.println(al.nome);
        System.out.println("------------------------");
    }
  }
}
```

Fiquei com dúvida do trecho no código:

```
        for(Aluna al : new Aluna().listar()){
```

Eu sei que é um `foreach` e que lista dados. Mas instanciar uma classe e ter acesso logo a seu método na classe dentro do `foreach` eu achei estranho. Como se chama fazer esse tipo de coisa?

Não leve em consideração a falta de encapsulamento.

Comment: Que tipo de coisa? Fazer uma chamada de método? Não entendi bem a dúvida.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Independente do `foreach` o que está acontecendo é o uso de um valor sem precisar de uma variável.

Ao contrário do que muitos pensam uma variável nem sempre é necessária. A variável é apenas uma forma de armazenar um valor. Você pode trabalhar com valores diretamente. Claro que há situações que é desejável armazenar um valor para uso posterior.

Então o código

```
new Aluna().listar()
```

poderia ser escrito como

```
Aluna aluna = new Aluna()
ArrayList<Aluna> alunas = aluna.listar()
```

e usando no `for`

```
for (Aluna al : alunas) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/ListObjects.java).

Mas pra que criar essas variáveis? O que elas acrescentam ao código? Nada! Então o código usado na pergunta instancia a classe e no lugar de armazenar o objeto gerado na instanciação ele já é imediatamente usado para chamar o método `listar()` que por sua vez devolve um `ArrayList` para o `foreach` iterar.

De fato há alguns problemas nesta classe e não é só o encapsulamento. Ok fazer isso rapidamente para exemplificar, mas uma `Aluna` não deveria acumular uma lista de alunas. Note como é estranho ter uma lista alunas dentro de uma aluna.

Comment: Mas Arraylist implementa List. Aparentemente a assinatura ser list e se retornar um arraylist não gera erro.

Comment: Exatamente, @DiegoFelipe. Não tem como ser gerado erro se a classe possui um contrato de implementação com a especificada na assinatura do retorno.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe é verdade, muita linguagem, confunde tudo :)

Comment: Okay. Você achou isso estranho @bigown? O que eu poderia guardar em um arrayList de Alunas então?

Comment: @AlineGonzaga deveria ser outro objeto, talvez, e só talvez outra classe. Tente explicar porque uma aluna pode ter várias alunas dentro dela? Não é estranho? Pense nos objetos como coisas reais. Se a relação parecer absurda em um objeto, é porque tem algum errado.

Comment: Não consigo entender isso. É muita abstração para mim...Você pensa no nível de como guardar isso no banco?

Comment: É, abstração é um treco complicado. Guardar no banco é algo até bem concreto. Mas neste caso não tem nada de banco aí, estou falando só deste código. Tudo que você coloca no código tem que ter uma justificativa. Se não encontra uma é porque está errado. Qual sua justificativa para colocar uma LISTA DE ALUNAS dentro de UMA ALUNA?

Comment: Por que você não me fala uma solução para isso?

Comment: Simples, tire de dentro da aluna. Em qualquer outro lugar ficar melhor. Não posso dizer onde porque não sei qual é o intuito disto, só posso falar do que estou vendo.

Comment: @AlineGonzaga Este modelo *Aluna.listar()* faz parte de um pattern chamado *Active Record*, que usa o conceito de que a classe que representa um tipo de entidade cuida de todos os comportamentos relativos àquele tipo de entidade, inclusive sua persistência e recuperação. Uma exemplo de ferramenta muito respeitada que usa este pattern é o Ruby On Rails. Neste caso, é incorreto dizer que há uma "lista de alunas dentro de uma aluna" pois não estamos falando de uma Aluna mas sim da classe que representa entidades deste tipo. *Uma aluna* seria um objeto instância desta classe, e não a classe em si.

Comment: @AlineGonzaga Existe entretanto uma corrente de pensamento que acredita que uma classe que representa um tipo de entidade deveria ter apenas os comportamentos de negócio daquela entidade, e implementar persistência e recuperação seria responsabilidade demais para uma única classe, devendo portanto ser delegados a outro objeto (um repositório, por exemplo).

Comment: @AlineGonzaga Repare que o método *listar* e demais métodos de recuperação precisam ser métodos estáticos da classe *Aluna* para que eles pertençam à classe em vez de pertencer ao objeto. Já os métodos de persistência e remoção (*"salvar"*, "*deletar*"), no pattern Active Record, pertencem ao objeto de fato (são métodos de instância mesmo).

Comment: Depois eu estudo o que você está falando @Caffé. É que estou com uns erros aqui no meu projeto em .jsp.

Answer (score 4):

O foreach aguarda uma lista de elementos para sofrer iteração.

Se o método a ser invocado está assinado para retornar uma lista, não há nenhuma quebra de contrato entre os mecanismos envolvidos.

Quando você instancia a sua classe `Aluna` e logo em seguida faz a chamada ao seu método, será aquele método quem ficará encarregado de fornecer a lista que o foreach aguarda.

Caso ainda tenha ficado alguma lacuna no esclarecimento, coloque nos comentários.